# How to execute python script file (filename.py) using sikuli

Tags: python, sikuli

I have a python code (name.py) written in separate file and now I want to execute that code using sikuli.

I have tried
        openApp but its not working
could be possible I did some mistake but still looking for working logic.

Answer (score 0):

openApp is for running an application for example: openApp("calc.exe"). Please read about importing [python modules](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html). Technically this has nothing to do with Sikuli.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
run(python name.py)
```

I use similar approach to run my ruby scripts. My problem with it is that it waits for your script to finish, but it shouldn't realy be a problem in 90% of the cases.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to run the file as an executable script or use its contents?

As an executable script make sure that the file is a valid script and will execute something when called and then use `suprocess.Popen()` from another .py file to execute that file.

To use the module's contents make sure the file is on the PYTHONPATH and use `import name` and everything within name will now be available for use.